# Why Retrofit doesn't send POST request to the server?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

In API declaration I have this code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("loginByPass/")
fun loginByPassword(@Field("login") login: String,
                    @Field("password") password: String,
                    @Field("phone") phone: String) : Observable<AuthResponse>
```

Retrofit object I create this way:

```
class API {
    companion object {
        fun getRetrofitAPI() : IAPI {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)


            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SERVER_ADDRESS)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(IAPI::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

And request:

```
api.loginByPassword(login, password, "")
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({
                Log.w("USER_DB", "CODE: " + it.code)
            }, {
                this.sayError(it.localizedMessage)
            }).dispose()
```

And I have no response at all! In logs it seems like I haven't sent any request. Also I have seen sent packages - from emulator was sent nothing. I'm calling to server IP address by HTTP.
Could you give me piece of advice, what's the problem?

Comment: ca you add your error log messages

Comment: I doesn't have any error, because I doesn't have any response

Comment: maybe because of this `.dispose()`??

Comment: can you use it.printStackTrace() in onError()

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon you are right. dispose will cancel the request

Comment: @snitron remove `.dispose()` and try

Comment: Did you add Internet Permission on Android Manifest file?

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Thank you very much! I lost all day to find answer xD. Could you write an answer, I will pin it! Спасибо, весь день потратил на поиск))

Comment: @RajasekaranM thank you too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @DrawnRaccoon 's answer, .dispose() destroys the request, so I should use CompositeDisposable to collect all requests and dispose them in onDestroy() method.